# Pass a div just created by ngFor to a function in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am producing some divs using ngFor:

```
<div  *ngFor='let img of images'>
```

I want to pass the div just produced to a function. At first, I tried to just pass a number to the function

```
<div  *ngFor='let img of images' (being)="ToRunEachTime(img)">
```

where being is a directive like:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[being]'
})

export class beingDirective {
  @Output() being: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {      
     this.being.emit('anything'); 
  } 
}
```

This code works well and I am able to pass img (which is a number) each time to the function ToRunEachTime. However, I wish to pass the whole div which is just created by *ngFor to this function. I tried:

```
<div  *ngFor='let img of images' (being)="ToRunEachTime($event)">
```

but the function

```
ToRunEachTime(event: Event){
var currentdiv= <HTMLDivElement>event.target;
}
```

gives me undefined. Any Help is appreciated!

Comment: in which module you have the directive?

Comment: A module called beingDirective and I am importing it to my main component using  import {beingDirective} from './being.directive'

Comment: you are emitting a string in this line `this.being.emit('anything'); ` then `event` in your `app.component.ts` will hold `anything` value

Comment: That is just a dummy event to notify that the element is created, so I can call my actual function.

Comment: check my answer below, is it helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your directive you are emitting a `string` which does not contain the `target` property

```
export class beingDirective {
  @Output() being: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  constructor(private el:ElementRef,private renderer:Renderer2) {}
  ngOnInit() {      
     this.being.emit(this.el.nativeElement); 
  } 
}
```

If you are looking to emit any Browser event you should be adding a `HostListener` as below and emit that event

```
@HostListener('mouseover', ['$event']) onClick(event) {
     this.being.emit(event);
}
```

This will give you the `target` element. Updated the demo.

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pass-a-div-just-created-by-ngfor-to-a-function-in-angular)

Comment: I still get undefined when I set in (being)="ToRunEachTime($event)" and there is an alert in ToRunEachTime like alert(event.target)

Comment: in this case `$event`  is your HTML element which will not have `target` property so your getting undefined. `console.log(event)` and see the object structure

Comment: It is [object HTMLDivElement]. But why using target gives me undefined? how can I get Id of the element for example from this even object?

Comment: you dont have a `target` inside your element. it is not an `event` it is the `elementRef` which you are emitting. so it does not have `target` property